# NoClassDefFound is thrown on attempt to create JedisConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I have generated a brand new springboot project using SpringInitializr in my IntellijIDEA (v.2022.2.1). As a result I got pom.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>redis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redis-spring</name>
    <description>redis-spring</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.3</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The problem is when I try to create an instance of JedisConnectionFactory(like `JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();`) it throws an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/JedisClientConfig`. The project does not have any code nor configuration...except for the default that was generated by Initialzr. What could be the reason for the class not to be in the classpath?

Comment: Please do a `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*jedis` (or the Gradle alternative)..this sounds very [like a version clash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109704/592355) ..urgents suspect: Test-Containers!

Answer (score 2):

It turned to be trivial - I just had to add `jedis` dependency explicitly in pom.xml